# Process arguments dont work in C#, but they do in cmd

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass 2 paths and 1 string to a file, but it does not work and I do not know why.

When doing it in CMD, it works perfectly.

Debugging the app I am trying to feed the arguments to, the paths look fine but I keep getting weird last errors like "invalid handle" or "share error" (Refering to the Share parameter of the CreateFile API) or "invalid parameter", but I get none of that 5 seconds later when I try in CMD

Here is how I am feeding the paths:

first:

```
OpenFileDialog FileDlg = new OpenFileDialog();

                if (DialogResult.OK == FileDlg.ShowDialog()) {
                    FilePath = FileDlg.FileName;
                }
```

second:

```
 SaveFileDialog SaveDlg = new SaveFileDialog();

                if (DialogResult.OK == SaveDlg.ShowDialog()) {
                    FileOutPath = SaveDlg.FileName;
                }
```

process startup:

```
      string Args = FilePath + " " + FileOutPath + " " + "1";
        Process Proc = new Process();
        Proc.StartInfo.FileName = FileToStart;
        Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Args;
        Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        Proc.Start();

        StreamReader OutRead = Proc.StandardOutput;
        string Out = OutRead.ReadToEnd();

        Proc.WaitForExit();
        Proc.Close();

        LogRichTextBox.Text = Out;
```

Initially, it was just a `Process.Start("file", "args")` call, that did also not work.

the first path is a local file, so I do not pass an absolute path, but just the executable name ("abc.exe"), but the second one is an absolute path ("C:\Users\X\Destkop\cba.exe")

What am I missing?

Comment: can you show us how are you passing the complete arguments? you can also try logging the values in both the case and compare

Comment: What do you mean how I am passing the complete arguments? And I have used MessageBox to print it and it prints the same thing, but on .NET it has `\\' while in my other app (C) it prints `\`, but its the same after passing with CMD. And I believe Windows filesystem is not case sensitive anyways, isnt it?

Comment: what does this means ? \\' while in my other app (C) it prints

Comment: messed up the formatting. The path shows up like `C:\\Users\\...` in my C# app, while in the app I am passing the arguments to it shows up as `C:\Users\...`

Comment: I could mention the app I am passing the parameters to has a wmain() main function, it receives UNICODE strings, but I believe .NET is UNICODE

Comment: There are 3 issues 1) Are you an admin.  VS doesn't run with Admin unless you create a shortcut and then start VS by right click shortcut and select Run as Admin.  The Users folder unless you own the file will not run 2) Is abc.exe in same folder as the c# executable.  Without full pathname c# will look for any file in same folder as the c# executable. 3) How do you know it is not running?  Is the executable terminating?  Your code will not continue until the exe terminates since you are using Proc.WaitForExit.

Comment: 1) I am not, neither was I in CMD, but I tried running as admin and it is the same 2) It is, but that isn't the path causing issue, its the full path that is causing issues. 3) As you can see in the code, I am passing the output of the console to a richtextbox, thats where  I can see the last errors and where it stops working

Comment: Excuse me for arriving late: is the problem that when you try to execute `FileToStart` you get all these errors when it tries to do things with `FilePath` and `FileOutPath`?

Comment: Are there any spaces in `FilePath` or `FileOutPath`?

Comment: Does `FileToStart` execute successfully, apart from the trouble with the arguments?

Comment: @AnnL. No problem. There are no spaces in either with the paths I tested with, and FileToStart does execute properly, I am getting its console output in a rich text box, hence why I know what is going wrong on the FileToStart side, but not on the C# side

Comment: So, when you say in comment #4 that the path shows up with "\" as "\\", you mean, when you examine it while debugging? Or does it also show up that way when you do a MessageBox (as I think you mentioned)?

Comment: When debugging. When printing, it is exactly the same both in C# and the app I am trying to pass the arguments to

Comment: When you say the first path is a local file, is it in the same directory as `FileToStart`'s executable?

Comment: it just occurred to me: it's `FileToStart` that's having the errors, right? When you execute it via C# in this way? Maybe we need to see what that program is doing with the arguments.

Comment: Yeah, it's in the same directory as `FileToStart`. The program passes it to a `CreateFile` Windows API call, and that's where the errors start occuring.Mentioned them in the OP and also mentioned I do not understand why those happen, but I assume the path is somehow getting screwed up when I am passing it trough C#

Comment: Is it necessary to use the Windows API call? You can't do what you want within .NET?

Comment: It's a very, very large program that does a lot more stuff, .NET served as an easy way to pass different options to it, It's fine if ya can't think of anything as a fix, it seems nobody really can. I tried passing the arguments to it with a `CreateProcess` p/invoke, and that also did not work, so there must be something wrong with either the paths or how I am passing them

Comment: Is it possible to debug `FileToStart`? I'm assuming it's a .NET program.

Comment: Oh, I see (about `FileToStart` being a big long program.)  This is a random thought, but could you achieve what you want with a PowerShell program, maybe? Or even an old-fashioned batch file?

Comment: You could generate a .bat file that invokes `FileToStart` with the desired parameters, and then execute that ....  You'd have no need to mess with parameter-passing to processes, because you'd just execute a parameterless batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try wrapping both filenames in quotes:

```
string Args = "\"" + FilePath + "\" \"" + FileOutPath + "\" 1";
```

So it'd look likes this when you pass it:

```
"{FilePath}" "{FileOutPath}" 1
```